# Bash script for check pem files certs and send mail if expire

Tags: linux, bash

can someone help me to finish a script in bash for check openssl certificates and send mail before expire ? I tried with some code from here, but i don't know exactly how to continue

```
location=/home/merox/Desktop/*.pem ;
server=$HOSTNAME;

for pem in $location; do
   printf '%s: %s\n' \
      certexpire=$(date -d "$(: | openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$pem"|cut -d= -f 2)" --iso-8601) \
      "$pem"
done | sort

OUTPUT:
certexpire=2019-05-25: /home/merox/Desktop/key_me.pem
certexpire=2019-05-25: /home/merox/Desktop/key_merox.pem
certexpire=2021-07-14: /home/merox/Desktop/cert_me.pem
```

Comment: What does it print? How do you want to continue?

Comment: Hi, this is the output: certexpire=2019-05-25: /home/merox/Desktop/key_me.pem
certexpire=2019-05-25: /home/merox/Desktop/key_merox.pem
certexpire=2021-07-14: /home/merox/Desktop/cert_me.pem and i want to notify me on the mail with 7 days before one of this certs expire

Comment: Please edit your post and put that in the post. So 1. - you want to filter the list with only those certificates that will expire in less then 7 days - and 2. - you want to send that list via mail. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 2):

Comments in code.

```
# So, let's take the files from find and save them in an array
# Using globulation '*' is less secure.
IFS='\n' files=($(find /home/merox/Desktop -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pem'))


# one week in seconds
one_week=$((7 * 24 * 60 * 60))
# current time in seconds since epoch
now=$(date "+%s")
# for each file we want to check
for pem in "${files[@]}"; do
   # They expire at this time in seconds since epoch
   expires_at=$(date -d "$(: | openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$pem"|cut -d= -f 2)" +%s)
   # the difference
   expires_in=$((expires_at - now))
   # if the will expire in less then one_week
   if (( expires_in < one_week )); then
      # just print them
      printf "%s\n" "$pem"
   fi
done |
sort |
# I leave it to you on how to configure sendmail on your PC
sendmail -v "name@mail.com"
```

Comment: Thank you so much :), i added this for mail " mail -n -s "Certificate expiration warning for" my_mail@mail.com; " because i already have exim4 configurated on the server, i will past now the output after i run the script

Comment: I checked now the mail, looks fine, but one of this certificates will expire in 2020 not in 7 days

Comment: the expiration check is available as the `-checkend arg` option, where `arg` is the number of seconds to expiration, so `openssl x509 -checkend "$one_week" -noout -in "$pem"` should be enough, no need to parse the date, nor add `now`, just check the return value `@?`, whether it's `0` (will not expire), or `1` (will expire)